# When you remove an image from git and commit then add the same file back and commit, does git store the image twice?

Tags: image, git

For example: I remove a large image from the project and commit. I know the image is still saved in there in the history. Later, I'm asked to add the exact same file back into the repo. Does git know it already has that file in the history and use the same data or does it save the large image into the history again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blob hash should be the same at least but im not sure if and how git might use some kind of delta compression. A tip is to inspect your repository with `git ls-tree`.

```
git ls-tree HEAD path/to/image
git ls-tree <older-commit-with-image> path/to/image
```

Comment: Git does not use delta compression, the image is stored only once, assuming it does not change.

Comment: Are you sure? the man page says "When first created, objects are stored in individual files, but for efficiency may later be compressed together into "pack files"." but compressions seams to only be done if you use `git gc`.

Comment: Pack files are collections of several blobs, they have nothing to do with delta compression.

Comment: Ok but not entirely convinced :) The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) states that "... This can consume a large amount of hard disk space quickly, so objects can be combined into packs, which use delta compression to save space, storing blobs as their changes relative to other blobs."

Comment: @MattiasWadman: Yes, but if two identical images have been checked in, they're both the same blob.  Two *nearly* identical images, if combined into packs, will occupy less than twice the space of one image; two *identical* images should occupy just the space of one image, plus some overhead metadata.